# Translate $\frac{1}{x}$ into given function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac1x.$$  Describe the transformations performed onto $f(x)$ in order for the resulting function to be $$y=\dfrac{5-2x}{x+4}.$$ I don't know how I would come about what the shifts are, and what the stretches are. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The most difficult part of this problem would be to identify the vertical translation.  That can be done by decomposing the numerator:

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac1x\\
y=\frac{5-2x}{x+4}&=\frac{-2x\color{blue}{-8+8}+5}{x+4}\\
y&=\frac{-2(x+4)+13}{x+4}\\
y&=\frac{13}{x+4}-2\\
y&=13\bigg(\frac1{x+4}\bigg)-2\\
y&=13f(x+4)-2
\end{align}

Therefore, we have a vertical expansion by a factor of $13$, a horizontal translation $4$ units left, and vertical translation $2$ units down.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Notice that
$$\frac{5-2x}{x+4}=\frac{-2(x+4)+13}{x+4}=-2+\frac{13}{x+4}.$$